# Program to take input from command line into an array and find the biggest among them

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I am new to Ruby and just can't figure out how you take input for an array from a user and display it.If anyone could clear that I can add my logic to find the biggest number.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

puts "Enter the size of the array"
n = gets.chomp.to_i
puts "enter the array elements"
variable1=Array.new(n)

for i in (0..n)
  variable1[i]=gets.chomp.to_i
end

for i in (0..n)
  puts variable1
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about capturing the array in one line?

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

puts "Enter a list of numbers"

list = gets   # Input something like "1 2 3 4" or "3, 5, 6, 1"

max = list.split.map(&:to_i).max

puts "The largest number is: #{max}"
```

Comment: Thank you ! Still stuck with old C programming habits. The program that I wrote prints only the last element. Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Instead of 'puts variable1' you should 'puts variable1[i]'. Also, don't need to chomp, to_i will take care of that.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing it ok. But try this little change

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

puts "Enter the size of the array"
n = (gets.chomp.to_i - 1)
puts "enter the array elements"
variable1=Array.new(n)

for i in (0..n)
  variable1[i]=gets.chomp.to_i
end

puts variable1
```

or for undefined number of values here is one way

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

puts "enter the array elements (type 'done' to get out)"
input = gets.chomp
arr = []
while input != 'done'
  arr << input.to_i
  input = gets.chomp
end

puts arr
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that this is a little bit more elegant solution.

```
    puts "Please enter numbers separated by spaces:"
    s = gets

    a = s.split(" ")

    #Displays array
    puts a 

    #Displays max element   
    puts a.max
```

First you collect the series of numbers from the user, then you use a split method on the string, which converts it to the array. If you want to use some other separator, like "," than you can write s.split(","). After that you can use your logic to find the biggest number or you could just use max method.

Comment: I'm sorry, I havent realised that Tanzeeb already gave you the good answer, my mobile web browser fooled me.

Answer (score 1):

Some feedback:

- `chomp.to_i` is a bit redundant, since the latter will also remove newlines.
- `for x in y` is not commonly seen in idiomatic Ruby code. It basically behaves like `each` with slightly different scoping rules and probably should have been removed from the language a while ago.
- Ruby arrays are dynamic, so no need to preinitialize them. Something like `(1..n).map { gets.to_i }` would also produce the array you need.
- Displaying it can then be done like this: `array.each { |n| puts n }`

Alternatively you can use the `strip` approach outlined before, take the numbers as command line arguments in [ARGV](http://ruby.about.com/od/rubyfeatures/a/argv.htm) or pipe into your program using [ARGF](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html).